# Does the size of an int depend on the compiler and/or processor?

Tags: c++, c, types

Would the size of an integer depend upon the  compiler, OS and processor?

Comment: i answered it was processor...probably i was wrong:(

Comment: Perhaps you should retitle your question post?  You only seemed to be concerned with the size of an int, not a char (which is by definition of size 1 regardless of compiler or processor).

Comment: Related SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/c-size-of-int-long-etc

Comment: Almost duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680111/int32-vs-int64-vs-int-in-c-closed

Comment: *"why there is a close vote?"* A person with more than 100 questions to his credit should know to search first...

Comment: It's important to remember that "int" and "integer" are two different things: `int` is one of several integer types.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on how far from practical considerations we are willing to get.

Ultimately, in theory, everything in C and C++ depends on the compiler and only on the compiler. Hardware/OS is of no importance at all. The compiler is free to implement a hardware abstraction layer of *any* thickness and emulate absolutely anything. There's nothing to prevent a C or C++ implementation from implementing the `int` type of any size and with any representation, as long as it is large enough to meet the minimum requirements specified in the language standard. Practical examples of such level of abstraction are readily available, e.g. programming languages based on "virtual machine" platform, like Java.

However, C and C++ are intended to be highly *efficient* languages. In order to achieve maximum efficiency a C or C++ implementation has to take into account certain considerations derived from the underlying hardware. For that reason it makes a lot of sense to make sure that each basic type is based on some representation directly (or almost directly) supported by the hardware. In that sense, the size of basic types do depend on the hardware.

In other words, a specific C or C++ implementation for a 64-bit hardware/OS platform is absolutely free to implement `int` as a 71-bit 1's-complement signed integral type that occupies 128 bits of memory, using the other 57 bits as padding bits that are always required to store the birthdate of the compiler author's girlfriend. This implementation will even have certain practical value: it can be used to perform run-time tests of the portability of C/C++ programs. But that's where the practical usefulness of that implementation would end. Don't expect to see something like that in a "normal" C/C++ compiler.

Comment: Some of the other answers given are perfectly valid and correct, but I like this one best because it tries to give a deeper and more well-rounded explanation.

Comment: I'll just quote the C++ standard for completeness: "Plain ints have the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution environment." It's up to the compiler writer to decide what "natural" means.

Comment: And the C standard has similar wording: "A ‘‘plain’’ **int** object has the natural size suggested by the
architecture of the execution environment (large enough to contain any value in the range
**INT_MIN** to **INT_MAX** as defined in the header **<limits.h>**)."  The part about `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` isn't all that helpful, since they're defined as the lower and upper bounds of type `int`.

Comment: I haven't understood your answer.Can you please improve your answer by discussing the roles hardware,OS,compiler play the role in deciding the size of data types such as `int`. The opening line says everything depends upon compiler but then you mention there are some hardware constraints for efficiency.Can you discuss this please.

Comment: @Y.E.P: I don't see the contradiction. "Hardware constraints" are not really *constraints* at all. They are merely *suggestions* that have to be followed in order to result in the most efficient code. However, if you don't care about the maximum achievable efficiency of the compiled code, then you can implement a compiler that completely ignores any hardware considerations.

Comment: I'd say the practical usefulness could go a little bit further. What if the compiler author needs to remember his girlfriend's birthdate? :v

Comment: I like the idea that the compiler can do anything.  I'm going to implement a _fractal_ int, where what you're storing is the entropy of an integer, and what you get back is heat.

Answer (score 41):

Yes, it depends on both processors (more specifically, ISA, instruction set architecture, e.g., x86 and x86-64) and compilers including programming model. For example, in 16-bit machines, sizeof (int) was 2 bytes. 32-bit machines have 4 bytes for `int`. It has been considered `int` was the *native* size of a processor, i.e., the size of register. However, 32-bit computers were so popular, and huge number of software has been written for 32-bit programming model. So, it would be very confusing if 64-bit computer would have 8 bytes for `int`. Both Linux and Windows remain 4 bytes for `int`. But, they differ in the size of `long`.

Please take a look at the 64-bit programming model like **LP64** for most *nix and **LLP64** for Windows:

- http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#64-bit_data_models

Such differences are actually quite embarrassing when you write code that should work both on Window and Linux. So, I'm always using `int32_t` or `int64_t`, rather than `long`, via [stdint.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h).

Comment: A small typo, you mentioned that `sizeof(int)` is 16 on a 16-bit machine, but it is more likely to be 2.

Comment: If you need a type that is "at least 32 bits", then `long` suffices, and shouldn't cause a problem if it's *too* long.  The major exception is when you're directly reading from or writing to an on-disk or network format.

Comment: @caf - never assume long is >= 32 bits. It probably is, but don't count on it. I used a compiler that used *1* bit for `short`, *8* bits for `int`, and *16* bits for `long`.  Use `int32_t` instead.

Comment: @MarkLakata: Whatever language that compiler was compiling, it wasn't C.  `long` must be able to represent all numbers in the range -2147483647 to 2147483648.

Comment: @caf - you are correct as far as ANSI C goes. `short` can't be 1 bit either, and `int` can't be 8-bits.  But the real world is never 100% compliant with anything.  If you don't believe me, here is the reference manual: http://www.ccsinfo.com/downloads/CReferenceManual.pdf  see page 37

Comment: @MarkLakata: If you can't trust the size of `long`, mandated by the standard, then you can't trust the size of `int32_t` either, since that *also* derives its guaranteed size from the standard.

Comment: Thanks ! This url is awesome , I had a buggy piece of code that typedefed uint32 as long on a *nix platform which is wrong according Lp64 model.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it would. Did they mean "which would it depend on: the compiler or the processor"? In that case the answer is basically "both." Normally, `int` won't be bigger than a processor register (unless that's smaller than 16 bits), but it could be smaller (e.g. a 32-bit compiler running on a 64-bit processor). Generally, however, you'll need a 64-bit processor to run code with a 64-bit int.

Comment: First part of your answer is very enlightening to me. I am confused when you said "you'll need a 64-bit processor to run code with a 64-bit int". I have learnt that int bigger than the native size of the machine can be handled by the machine by breaking it down in smaller chunks. there would be some performance penalty. isn't that the case?

Comment: @Sarurabh: I was commenting very specifically about the type named `int`. Many (most?) 32-bit compilers have a 64-bit type, but it'll have a different name (e.g., `__int64` or `long long`).

Answer (score 7):

Based on some recent research I have done studying up for firmware interviews:

The most significant impact of the processors bit architecture ie, 8bit, 16bit, 32bit, 64bit is how you need to most efficiently store each byte of information in order to best compute variables in the minimum number of cycles.

The bit size of your processor tells you what the natural word length the CPU is capable of handling in one cycle. A 32bit machine needs 2 cycles to handle a 64bit double if it is aligned properly in memory. Most personal computers were and still are 32bit hence the most likely reason for the C compiler typical affinity for 32bit integers with options for larger floating point numbers and long long ints.

Clearly you can compute larger variable sizes so in that sense the CPU's bit architecture determines how it will have to store larger and smaller variables in order to achieve best possible efficiency of processing but it is in no way a limiting factor in the definitions of byte sizes for ints or chars, that is part of compilers and what is dictated by convention or standards.

I found this site very helpful, http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/9705, for explaining how the CPU's natural word length effects how it will chose to store and handle larger and smaller variable types, especially with regards to bit packing into structs. You have to be very cognizant of how you chose to assign variables because larger variables need to be aligned in memory so they take the fewest number of cycles when divided by the CPU's word length. This will add a lot of potentially unnecessary buffer/empty space to things like structs if you poorly order the assignment of your variables.

Answer (score 2):

The simple and correct answer is that it depends on the compiler. It doesn't mean architecture is irrelevant but the compiler deals with that, not your application. You could say more accurately it depends on the (target) architecture of the compiler for example if its 32 bits or 64 bits.

Consider you have windows application that creates a file where it writes an `int` plus other things and reads it back. What happens if you run this on both 32 bits and 64 bits windows? What happens if you copy the file created on 32 bits system and open it in 64 bits system?

You might think the size of int will be different in each file but no they will be the same and this is the crux of the question. You pick the settings in compiler to target for 32 bits or 64 bits architecture and that dictates everything.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf

"3 Data representation" contains good overview of what compilers do with integral types.

Answer (score 0):

Data Types Size depends on Processor, because compiler wants to make CPU easier accessible the next byte. for eg: if processor is 32bit, compiler may not choose int size as 2 bytes[which it supposed to choose 4 bytes] because accessing another 2 bytes of that int(4bytes) will take additional CPU cycle which is waste. If compiler chooses int as 4 bytes CPU can access full 4 bytes in one shot which speeds your application.

Thanks

Comment: This is bogus: "Data Types Size depends on Processor, because compiler wants to make CPU easier accessible the next byte" The compiler is not a person, it has no wants. You can implement the compiler whichever way you want. Efficiency of the generated code, in whatever metric, is a concern, but is not a concern where the standard is concerned. As some other answerer has said, you're free to produce a binary image with the date of birth of your girlfriend intespersed between every instruction :) Your abstract discussion of what a CPU might or might not do w.r.t. cycles etc is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Size of the int is equal to the word-length that depends upon the underlying ISA. Processor is just the hardware implementation of the ISA and the compiler is just the software-side implementation of the ISA. Everything revolves around the underlying ISA. Most popular ISA is Intel's IA-32 these days. it has a word length of 32bits or 4bytes. 4 bytes could be the max size of 'int' (just plain int, not short or long) compilers. based on IA-32, could use.

Answer (score 0):

size of data type basically depends upon the type of compiler and compilers are designed on the basis of architecture of processors so externally data type can be considered to be compiler dependent.for ex  size of integer is 2 byte in 16 bit tc compiler but 4 byte in gcc compiler although they are executed in same processor

Answer (score -6):

Yes , I found that size of int in turbo C was 2 bytes where as in MSVC compiler it was 4 bytes.

Basically the size of int is the size of the processor registers.

Comment: "Basically the size of int is the size of the processor registers." - This is incorrect, see other answers.