# integer size in c depends on what?

Tags: c

Size of the integer depends on what?

Is the size of an int variable in C dependent on the machine or the compiler?

Comment: I think the correct term is "implementation dependent".

Comment: Is it dependent on processor like 16 bit or 32 bit??

Comment: exact duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331751/does-the-size-of-an-int-depend-on-the-compiler-and-or-processor

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's implementation-dependent.  The C standard only requires that:

- `char` has at least 8 bits
- `short` has at least 16 bits
- `int` has at least 16 bits
- `long` has at least 32 bits
- `long long` has at least 64 bits (added in 1999)
- sizeof(char) ≤ sizeof(short) ≤ sizeof(int) ≤ sizeof(long) ≤ sizeof(long long)

In the 16/32-bit days, the *de facto* standard was:

- `int` was the "native" integer size
- the other types were the minimum size allowed

However, 64-bit systems generally did *not* make `int` 64 bits, which would have created the awkward situation of having three 64-bit types and no 32-bit type.  *Some* compilers expanded `long` to 64 bits.

Comment: <<awkward situation of having three 64-bit types and no 32-bit type.       Here you meant if int is made 64 bit then the  3 data types (int, long, long long) becomes 64bit. To avoid this, int is intentionally made as 32 bit.  Also, with 64 bit in place, this statement NO LONGER holds good "int was the "native" integer size".

Answer (score 10):

Formally, representations of all fundamental data types (including their sizes) are compiler-dependent and only compiler-dependent. The compiler (or, more properly, the *implementation*) can serve as an abstraction layer between the program and the machine, completely hiding the machine from the program or distorting it in any way it pleases.

But in practice compilers are designed to generate the most efficient code for given machine and/or OS. In order to achieve that the fundamental data types should have natural representation for the given machine and/or OS. In that sense, these representations are indirectly dependent on the machine and/or OS.

In other words, from the abstract, formal and pedantic point of view the compiler is free to completely ignore the data type representations specific to the machine. But it makes no practical sense. In practice compilers make full use of data type representations provided by the machine.

Still, if some data type is not supported by the machine, the compiler can still provide that data type to the programs by implementing its support at the compiler level ("emulating" it). For example, 64-bit integer types are normally available in 32-bit compilers for 32-bit machines, even though they are not directly supported by the machine. Back in the day the compilers would often provide compiler-level support for floating-point types for machines that were not equipped with floating-point co-processor (and therefore did not support floating-point types directly).

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine.

Comment: It makes practical sense for cross compilation. Add that and this answer is near perfection. Actually, you could just clarify that "machine" refers to the **target** machine.

Answer (score 7):

It depends primarily on the compiler. For example, if you have a 64-bit x86 processor, you can use an old 16-bit compiler and get 16-bit ints, a 32-bit compiler and get 32-bit ints, or a 64-bit compiler and get 64-bit ints.

It depends on the processor to the degree that the compiler targets a particular processor, and (for example) an ancient 16-bit processor simply won't run code that targets a shiny new 64-bit processor.

The C and C++ standards do guarantee some minimum size (indirectly by specifying minimum supported ranges):

```
char: 8 bits
short: 16 bits
long: 32 bits
long long: 64 bits
```

The also guarantee that the sizes/ranges are strictly non-decreasing in the following order: char, short, int, long, and long long<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup>long long is specified in C99 and C++0x, but some compilers (e.g., gcc, Intel, Comeau) allow it in C++03 code as well. If you want to, you can persuade most (if not all) to reject `long long` in C++03 code.

Answer (score 2):

As MAK said, it's implementation dependent.  That means it depends on the compiler.  Typically, a compiler targets a single machine so you can also think of it as machine dependent.

Comment: That means designing of the compiler is according to the machin??

Comment: Sometimes.  Some compilers (such as gcc) are cross platform and can target multiple machines.  Some compilers target only a single machine (this is especially true for for compilers that target embedded processors).  If I remember correctly, the rules for the size of data types go soemthing like this: sizeof(char) == 1; sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the size of data types is *implementation dependent*. This means that it is entirely up to the implementer (i.e. the guy writing the compiler) to choose what it will be.

So, in short it depends on the compiler. But often it is simpler to just use whatever size it is easiest to map to the word size of the underlying machine - so the compiler often uses the size that fits the best with the underlying machine.

Comment: But if we use 16 bit compiler like c compiler  it takes 16 bit and If we use vc++ on same machin  then it takes 32 bit then how it can use size of the underlying machin??

Comment: @shubhangi Motling: The underlying machine normally supports 16-bit integer types as well as 32-bit integer types. So there's no problem here at all.

Comment: @shubhangi See the second sentence of the answer, as well as the word "often", repeated twice.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on both the architecture (machine, executable type) and the compiler. C and C++ only guarantee certain minimums. (I think those are char: 8 bits, int: 16 bits, long: 32 bits)

C99 includes certain known width types like uint32_t (when possible). See [stdint.h](http://linux.die.net/man/3/uint32_t)

**Update**: Addressed Conrad Meyer's concerns.

Comment: It only mandates the fixed-width types if the hardware reasonably supports them.

Comment: @Conrad Meyer, Do you mean uint32_t won't be 32-bit on some machines, or that uint32_t won't be available on some machines? I only meant the former won't happen, but corrections are welcome.

Comment: `uint32_t` MUST be 32 bits if the hardware supports 32-bit integers, and not defined at all if doesn't.  If you need to support non-16/32/64-bit systems, use the `uint_leastN_t` types instead.

Comment: That is indeed what I meant. Thanks for the confirmation and for saying it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the running environment no matter what hardware you have. If you are using a 16bit OS like DOS, then it will be 2 bytes. On a 32 bit OS like Windows or Unix, it is 4 bytes and so on. Even if you run a 32 bit OS on a 64 bit processor, the size will be 4 bytes only. I hope this helps.

Comment: It would help more if it were accurate. While the compiler's default settings generally match the running environment, cross compilation is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The size of an Integer Variable depends upon the type of compiler:

- if you have a 16 bit compiler:

  ```
  size of int is 2 bytes
  char holds 1 byte
  float occupies 4 bytes
  ```
- if you have a 32 bit compiler:

  size of each variable is just double of its size in a 16 bit compiler

  ```
  int hold 4 bytes
  char holds 2 bytes
  float holds 8 bytes
  ```

Same thing happens if you have a 64 bit compiler, and so on.