# Number of bits in an integer

Tags: c, compiler-construction

The number of bits in an integer in C is compiler and machine dependent. What is meant by this? Does the number of bits in an int vary with different C compilers and different processor architecture? Can you illustrate what it means?

Comment: Exactly, it does.

Comment: It depends upon different processor architecture, like 32 bit CPU, has 4 bytes, or 64 bits CPU, has 8 bytes.. etc.

Comment: @OP It refers to **the size** of the integer. For example in x86 `sizeof(long)` is 4 while on amd64 `sizeof(long)` is typically 8.

Comment: This is a (dupiclate) question about the rules of a language, C, about one of its types, `int`; not about people making computers with more capacity so that we the users can store larger stuff in them. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11438985/96780) from the duplicate question.

Comment: Please answer your homework or test questions yourself.

Comment: See also the related question [gcc - Size of integer in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7180196/96780) and its [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7180229/96780).

Comment: See also the related question [Does the size of an int depend on the compiler and/or processor?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2331751/96780) and its [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2331835/96780).

Answer (score 2):

This wikipedia article gives a good overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(data_type)

Types such as integers are represented in hardware. Hardware changes, and so do the size of certain types. The more bits in a type, the larger the number (for integers) or more precision you can store (for floating-point types).

There are some types which specifically specify the number of bits, such as `int16`.

Comment: Down-voting without an explanation isn't very constructive.

Comment: The place were Wikipedia explains sizes of types in C is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types.

Comment: The questioner was asking for an explanation about the fact that sizes can be different, not necessarily a list. I think my link was more useful in connection with the question.

Comment: I think the specification of types in a language is better understood by reading the rules of the language itself. But of course the OP will benefit from reading both links.

Answer (score 2):

It means exactly what it says and what you said in your own words.

For example, on some compilers and with some platforms, an `int` is 32 bits, on other compilers and platforms an `int` is 64 bits.

I remember long ago when I was programming on the Commodore Amiga, there were two different C compilers available from two different manufacturers. On one compiler, an `int` was 16 bits, on the other compiler an `int` was 32 bits.

You can use `sizeof` to determine how many bytes an `int` is on your compiler.

Comment: Manx (Aztec) and Lattice!

Comment: @JimBalter Exactly! I had Aztec C.