# C: Which data type sizes are correct?

Tags: c, memory, gdb, sizeof

1. Why do C and gdb output something different?
2. And how some data type sizes can even be equal? At least [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) says that all of these have different value ranges.

I have a 64-bit machine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

        printf("int: %d, long int: %d, long long int: %d\n", sizeof(int), sizeof(long int), sizeof(long long int));
}
```

```
$ gcc -g test.c
$ ./a.out
int: 4, long int: 8, long long int: 8
```

```
$ gdb -q
(gdb) p sizeof(int)
$1 = 4
(gdb) p sizeof(long int)
$2 = 4
(gdb) p sizeof(long long int)
$3 = 8
```

Comment: First use correct format specifier for `size_t` (`"%zu"`). Second, the sizes depend on the compiler, not on the architecture alone. Try running `gdb` with this specific application and see if the result changes.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. It seems like a bug in your debugger.

Comment: @PSkocik Is it necessary a bug? Can't be that this is `gdb` for different arch by default?

Comment: You are reading the Wikipedia article wrongly.  It gives the *minimum* ranges for various data types.  That is also what the ISO C language specification defines.  Conforming C language implementations may give any or all of them wider ranges, subject to some limitations.  Historically, the actual sizes and ranges of `int` and `long int` (and their unsigned analogues) have had a reasonably high propensity to vary among implementations, and they still do.

Comment: Also, Wikipedia *does not* say even that various types even all have different minimum ranges.  Compare its tabulated ranges for the `short int` type family with those of the `int` type family.

Comment: Thank you guys, this really clarified it for me. But I don't think it's a bug, because as @EugeneSh. said it depends on the compiler. Whats interesting, when I run the program with gdb and then print the sizes (with gdb), I got the same result as executing the program directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from the C code without GDB is defined by the compiler.

This post can help you with figuring out the sizes according to your machine:

[Size of integer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180196/size-of-integer-in-c)

on a 64 bit windows the size of long int is 4 bytes (like you got)
while on Mac this type is 8 bytes.

if you want precision while writing c code you should use "uintX_t" types from the stdint built in module.

for example: "int8_t, uint32_t ..."

This makes sure you will get the expected sizes regardless of the compiler or the machine you run on.

Comment: I understand, thank you. I will try the library and btw I executed the program on a Linux Ubuntu 20.04 system.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the native "main" types are compiler/target dependent.
The C standard defines the minimum sizes of each type, I'll quote Wikipedia:

> The minimum size for char is 8 bits, the minimum size for short and int is 16 bits,
>   for long it is 32 bits and long long must contain at least 64 bits. The type int
>   should be the integer type that the target processor is most
>   efficiently working with.

So, it seems gdb assumes a different machine here than your compiler does. Did you even load your debugging target into gdb? I would expect the sizes to match then.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yeah as I mentioned in a comment  under the main post if I run the program with gdb and then print the sizes with gdb, they match

Comment: Please note that the language does not specify the *size* of each type, only the minimum *range of values* the type must be able to represent.  You can infer the minimum number of bits from that, but there's nothing that stops an implementation from using a larger size than it needs, or from using extra padding bits.

Answer (score 1):

On a 64-bit x86 GNU/Linux system, gdb is usually configured to use the `i386` architecture (32-bit ABI) by default:

```
$ gdb -q
(gdb) p sizeof(int)
$1 = 4
(gdb) p sizeof(long)
$2 = 4
(gdb) show arch
The target architecture is set automatically (currently i386)
```

That's on a Debian WSL system.

After you give gdb a target file, it will adjust appropriately:

```
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2,
for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped

$ gdb -q a.out
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) p sizeof(int)
$1 = 4
(gdb) p sizeof(long)
$2 = 8
(gdb) show arch
The target architecture is set automatically (currently i386:x86-64)
```