# data type ranges differing with operating systems

Tags: c

The 8-bit,16-bit,32-bit,64-bit operating systems have different data range for
integers,float and double values.

Is this the compiler or the processor that makes difference(8bit,16bit,32bit,64bit).

If in a network if a 16 bit integer data from one system is transferred to a 32 bit system 
or vice-versa will the data be correctly represented in memory.Please help me to understand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the size of an int depend on the compiler and/or processor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331751/does-the-size-of-an-int-depend-on-the-compiler-and-or-processor)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ultimately, it is up to the compiler.  The compiler is free to choose any data types it likes<sup>*</sup>, even if it has to emulate their behaviour with software routines.  Of course, typically, for efficiency it will try to replicate the native types of the underlying hardware.

As to your second question, yes, of course, if you transfer the raw representation from one architecture to another, it may be interpreted incorrectly (endianness is another issue).  That is why functions like `ntohs()` are used.

<sub>* Well, not literally anything it likes.  The C standard places some constraints, such as that an `int` must be at least as large as a `short`.</sub>

Comment: I think it rather replicates the types used by the underlying OS. E.g. on Linux 64bit on Intel, long int is 64 bit, while in Windows 64bit it is 32 bit, on the same processor. The native register type is 64 bit in both occasions.

Comment: Actually the C standard imposes some restrictions on what types the compiler may choose.  For instance, if `int` is 16 bits, `short` can't be 32 bits.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler (more properly the "implementation") is free to choose the sizes, subject to the limits in the C standard. The set of sizes offered by C for its various types depends in part on the hardware it runs on; i.e. the compiler makes the choice but, it (except in cases like Java where datatypes are explicitly independent of underlying hardware) is strongly influenced by what the hardware offers.

Answer (score 2):

It depends not on just the compiler and operating system. It is dictated by the architecture (processor at least).

When passing data between possibly different architectures they use special fixed size data type, e.g. `uint64_t`, `uint32_t` instead of `int`, `short` etc.

But the size of integers is not the only concern when communicating between computers with different architectures, there's a byte order issue too (try googling about BigEndian and LittleEndian)

Comment: Ultimately, though, it is the compiler that chooses what sizes/endianness/etc. to expose for its data types.  Not the hardware.

Comment: `uint64_t` etc need not exist on **all** implementations (think computers with 9-bit bytes).

Answer (score 1):

The size of a given type depends on the CPU and the conventions on the operating system.

If you want to have an int of a specific size, use the [stdint.h header <sup>*[wikipedia]*</sup>](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Stdint.h). It defines the `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64_t`, some others and their unsigned equivalent.

For communications between different computers, the protocol should define the sizes and byte order to use.

Comment: Ultimately, though, it is the compiler that chooses what sizes/endianness/etc. to expose for its data types.  Not the hardware.

Comment: That's right, but the compiler's choices depend on the hardware and conventions of the operating system.

Comment: Some compilers (for rare architectures) may not provide the fixed width types in the `<stdint.h>` header. They must be defined only for an architecture where it makes sense to have them (... think computers with 9-bit bytes).

Comment: @arnaud576875: Actually, the compiler can ignore the conventions of the hardware / operating system if it so chooses.

Answer (score 1):

In a network it has to be defined in the protocol which data sizes you have. For endianness, it is highly recommended to use big endian values.

If there weren't the issue with the APIs, a compiler would be free to set its `short`, `int`, `long` as it wants. Bot often, the API calls are connected to these types. E.g. the `open()` function returns an `int`, whose size should be correct.

But the types might as well be part of the ABI definition.