# What determines the size of integer in C?

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [size of int, long, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc)
>   [Does the size of an int depend on the compiler and/or processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331751/does-the-size-of-an-int-depend-on-the-compiler-and-or-processor)

I'm not sure if similar questions have been asked before on SO (Atleast, I couldn't find any while searching, so thought of asking myself).

What determines the size of `int` (and other datatypes) in `C`. I've read it depends on the machine/operating system/compiler, but haven't come across a clear/detailed enough explanation on things like what overrides the other, etc. Any explanation or pointers will be really helpful.

Comment: The C standard gives a minimum range of values for each type. The compiler is ultimately responsible for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331751/does-the-size-of-an-int-depend-on-the-compiler-and-or-processor is probably a better dupe.

Comment: [Does the size of an int depend on the compiler and/or processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2331751/608639), [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589575/608639)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ultimately the compiler does, but in order for compiled code to play nicely with system libraries, most compilers match the behavior of the compiler[s] used to build the target system.

So loosely speaking, the size of `int` is a property of the target hardware and OS (two different OSs on the same hardware may have a different size of `int`, and the same OS running on two different machines may have a different size of `int`; there are reasonably common examples of both).

All of this is also constrained by the rules in the C standard.  `int` must be large enough to represent all values between `-32767` and `32767`, for example.

Comment: Suppose CPU register is of `16-bit`. Then it would be good to keep `16 bit size of int` or it can be in `multiple of 16`? I mean in most previous compiler int was of 16 bit.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: the answer to that really depends on the goals of the system and the software that is intended to run on it.

Comment: Small correction. It's `-32768`.

Comment: @KingsIndian: no, it isn't; the C standard is quite clear on that point.  If a 16-bit 2s complement representation happens to be used, it will be able to represent `-32768`, but that isn't required.

Comment: @StephenCanon Just checked the standard. It's indeed `-32767` for SHRT_MIN and INT_MIN. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5):

`int` is the "natural" size for the platform, and in practice that means one of

- the processor's register size, or
- a size that's backward compatible with existing code-base (e.g. 32-bit `int` in Win64).

A compiler vendor is free to choose any size with ≥ 16 value bits, except that (for desktop platforms and higher) a size that doesn't work with OS' API will mean that few if any copies of the compiler are sold. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The size of C data types is constrained by the C standard, often constraints on the *minimum* size. The host environment (target machine + OS) may impose further restriction, i.e. constraints on the *maximum* size. And finally, the compiler is free to choose suitable values between these minimum and maximum values.

Generally, it's considered bad practice to make assumptions about the size of C data types. Besides, it's not necessary, since C will tell you:

- the `sizeof`-operator tells you an object's size in bytes
- the macro `CHAR_BITS` from limits.h tells you the number of bits per byte

Hence, `sizeof(foo) * CHAR_BITS` tells you the size of type `foo`, in bits, including padding.

Anything else is just assumptions. Note that the host environment may as well consist of 10.000 Chinese guys with pocket calculators and a huge blackboard, pulling size constraints out of thin air.

Answer (score 0):

SO does not know everything but Wikipedia, almost...
see [Integer_(computer_science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29#Common_integral_data_types)

Note (b) says:
"*The sizes of short, int, and long in C/C++ are dependent upon the implementation of the language; dependent on data model, even short can be anything from 16-bit to 64-bit. For some common platforms:

    On older, 16-bit operating systems, int was 16-bit and long was 32-bit.

    On 32-bit Linux, DOS, and Windows, int and long are 32-bits, while long long is 64-bits. This is also true for 64-bit processors running 32-bit programs.

    On 64-bit Linux, int is 32-bits, while long and long long are 64-bits.*"

Comment: (a) just posting a link isn't an answer (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers); at best it's a comment. (b) that link doesn't actually answer the question that was asked, and the information in that table is borderline misleading to boot.