# Is pack('i',1) always 4 bytes?

Tags: php, pack

On my machine `PHP_INT_SIZE` is `8` but `pack('i',1)` returns a 4 byte string anyway.

[The docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) say `i` is a "signed integer (machine dependent size and byte order)" but that doesn't appear to be true. Is it fixed at 4 bytes?

This means that `unpack('i',pack('i',PHP_INT_MAX))[1] !== PHP_INT_MAX` on 64-bit machines because half the data is lopped off.

Comment: Just reproduced in 64-bit Linux—so it's not necessarily a Windows-only issue due to lack of 64-bit integer.

Comment: "signed integer (machine dependent size and byte order)" does not mean its size should be equal to `PHP_INT_SIZE`, even if it's what everyone would except.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to remember that [PHP is written in C](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?t=4194&f=63) (in other words, it doesn't matter what PHP thinks an `int` is). Jumping off of the other answer about `sizeof(int)`, it looks like it's a relic of 32 bit [C compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2331768/2370483) (emphasis mine)

> Yes, it depends on both processors (more specifically, ISA,
>   instruction set architecture, e.g., x86 and x86-64) and compilers
>   including programming model. For example, in 16-bit machines, sizeof
>   (int) was 2 bytes. **32-bit machines have 4 bytes for int.** It has been
>   considered int was the native size of a processor, i.e., the size of
>   register. However, 32-bit computers were so popular, and huge number
>   of software has been written for 32-bit programming model. **So, it
>   would be very confusing if 64-bit computer would have 8 bytes for int.**
>   Both Linux and Windows remain 4 bytes for int. But, they differ in the
>   size of long.

So, in short, it could be 2 bytes but only if you have a 16 bit processor. In 32 and 64 bit systems, C seems to say `int` is 4 bytes in all cases. So, yes, `pack('i',1);` will always be 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes (mostly).

---

From PHP's source code (`pack.c`):

```
switch ((int) code) {
    //...

    case 'i': 
    case 'I':
        INC_OUTPUTPOS(arg,sizeof(int))
        break;

    //...
}
```

The function uses `sizeof(int)` (which in your case (and most cases [citation needed]) will be 4), rather than the value of `PHP_INT_SIZE`. Doesn't fully cover the question on "why?", but as the idea for the function was taken from Perl, PHP could just be going for similar functionality.

Comment: No. You are wrong. `sizeof(int)` will be different if you are on a 32, or 64 bit machine.

Comment: @true Can you provide a citation for that? I know it won't always be the same, but it seems to be 4 for me regardless (and similar results are reported here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc)