# Cast from "int" to "unsigned short" after applying bitwise operator "~"

Tags: c, casting

Static analysis tool I use raises a warning for this code :

```
uint16 var1 = 1U;
uint16 var2 = ~var1;
```

I check MISRA C 2004 rules and I find 10.5 rule :

> If the bitwise operators ~ and << are applied to an operand od underlying type *unsigned char* or *unsigned short*, the result shall be immediately cast to the underlying type of the operand.

Ok, it's not a problem, implicit cast is applied (I think "cast" means implicit or explicit cast). But 10.1 rule says :

> The value of an expression of integer type shall not be implicitly converted to a different underlying type the expression is complex.

An previous example of complex operation are : ~u16a

I change my code to :

```
uint16 var1 = 1U;
uint16 var2 = (uint16) ~var1;
```

And I obtain another warning : I think conversion of int negative value to unsigned int value not safe. I check C99 standard ([ISO C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf)) § 6.3.1.3 but I don't understand if conversion of *int* to *unsigned short* are clearly specified.

In [EmbeddedGurus article](http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2009/08/a-tutorial-on-signed-and-unsigned-integers/) I read :

```
c = (unsigned int) a; /* Since a is positive, this cast is safe */
```

My questions :

1. Have explicit conversion from *signed int* to *unsigned short* unspecified behavior ?
2. If yes, how to use complement operator with unsigned short in safe way ?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989343/how-is-shift-operator-evaluated-in-c) are some nice answers explaining numeric promotion

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The operands of the arithmetic and bitwise operators always undergo the *standard promotions* before the value is computed. Anything shorter than an `int` is promoted to either `int` or `unsigned int`, depending on the platform (i.e. depending on whether `int` can represent all values of the type that's being promoted).

On your platform, `uint16_t` is standard-promoted to `int`, since your `int` can represent all values of a `uint16_t`. Then the bitwise negation is applied to that `int` value, which is the cause of the problem.

To get a deterministic result independent of the platform, convert the value to an `unsigned int` yourself:

```
 uint16_t var2 = (uint16_t) ~((unsigned int) var1);
```

Note that this is always correct, since `unsigned int` is required to be able to represent all the values of a `uint16_t`.

Comment: What would be the correct way to write the code if the type in question had been `int32_t` rather than `int16_t`, since on some compilers `long` might be 64 bits, while on others `int` would be 16?

Comment: `int16_t` can always be promoted to `int`, should it actually need promotion, so you don't have to write anything. (That said, bitwise operations on signed integers are generally ill-advised.)

Comment: Hence my (intended) question about how one should write the code if the type had been `uint32_t` rather than `uint16_t`.  Casting to `unsigned int` would fail on platforms where `unsigned int` is 16 bits, and casting to `unsigned long` could result in value truncation if that type is 64 bits.  IMHO, for C to be decent language for writing portable code, it needs to include fixed-sized unsigned types *which would not promote*.

Comment: @supercat: Ask it as a separate question.

Comment: @Kerrek SB : Ok, I avoid integral promotion with explicit cast to a widening unsigned integer type. But use of "int" is a violation of 6.3 of MISRA rule (use of typedef that indicate size and signedness). Moreover, I think add precision of size is not a good idea because  it would make the code not independant of the plateform. But my first question is : explicit conversion from signed int to unsigned int is a non-safe conversion ? 6.10.3 says this a dangerous conversion because that implies loss of sign... but it's my goal, and explicit conversion does this means, no ?

Comment: @JérômeBurlando: I don't understand what "safe" means, so I cannot answer that. But as I said before, you should a) not use bit operations on signed integers because that's sort of meaningless, and b) not convert between signed and unsigned for no reason. The answer I gave solves all of those problems, though I'm not entirely sure if there's a MISRA compliant way. Maybe convert to `uintmax_t`, though that's gratuitous.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: If I understand, when I use bitwise operators on small interger type, it's a good idea to convert explicitly to widening unsigned interger type in order to avoid integral promotion resulting using signed integer type ?

Comment: @JérômeBurlando: Yes, that sounds right. That's a good summary.

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Have explicit conversion from signed int to unsigned short unspecified behavior ?

The conversion from signed to unsigned values is well specified it happens via modulo arithmetic is covered by section `6.3.1.3` *Signed and unsigned integers* from the C99 draft standard:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.<sup>49)</sup>

So for your case the negative number would be converted by repeatedly adding:

```
UMAX + 1
```

to the negative result until it is range of the unsigned type you are converting to.

For example the conversion of `-1` to an unsigned type always results in the max unsigned value since `-1 + UMAX + 1` is always `UMAX`.

> 2. If yes, how to use complement operator with unsigned short in safe way ?

What happens when you apply the `~` operator is that the value is bring promoted to *int* due to integer promotions being applied to the operand of `~`. Which is covered in section `6.5.3.3` *Unary arithmetic operators* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> The **integer promotions are performed on the operand**, and the result
>   has the promoted type. If the promoted type is an **unsigned type, the
>   expression ~E is equivalent to the maximum value representable in that
>   type minus E**.

Given the last sentence in the quoted paragraph perhaps casting to *unsigned int* first may lead to more intuitive results:

```
uint16 var2 = ~((unsigned int)var1);
```

and since you are required to apply an explicit cast then you end up with this:

```
uint16 var2 = (uint16) ~((unsigned int)var1);
```

Comment: The problem is that the value of `~1` can vary depending on `int`'s representation (e.g., -1 in one's complement, -2 in two's complement, etc.), so the result when converted to `unsigned short` may also be different.

Comment: @T.C. I removed that statement, as you point out out it was too broad