# Convert hexadecimal made up of 0's and 1's to binary equivalent

Tags: c, binary, hex, bit-manipulation

I need a hexadecimal number converted to another one representing the binary value of it (not the actual value though).

For example, if I have 0x0101, I would like to get 0b0101, which means 0x5. The hexadecimal I get at the beginning is always composed of 0's and 1's.

It could also be a way to convert 0xf00f to 0b1001 (0xf's to 0b1's instead of 0x1's to 0b1's), which means 0x9. Actually, the hexadecimal number I have at the beginning is composed of f's and 0's, but it's easy to get the f's replaced by 1's by dividing it by 0xf. Example:

```
uint16_t bitMask = 0xf0f0;
uint16_t nybbleMask = 0;

//do some bit manipulation with bitMask
//get nybbleMask == 0xc (0b1010)
```

or:

```
bitMask = bitMask / 0xf;
//bitMask is now 0x1010

//do some bit manipulation with bitmask
//get nybbleMask == 0xc (0b1010)
```

Edit: I know I could easily do it with a loop, but I was wondering if I could do something equivalent with bitwise opetator. Also, I don't have access to `math.h` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple problem, which I assume is homework.  @tom made it a bit harder than it needs to be.

You simply want to extract every 4th bit starting from the least significant, ignoring the 3 intervening zeros. I'll give you an algorithm. Writing the code shouldn't be hard:

```
let x be the hex coded binary number to convert
let val be the binary result value, initially zero
let n be the bit position we're currently finding, initially zero
while x is not zero
  let b be the least significant bit of x
  update val to be val or (b shifted left by n bits)
  increment n
  update x to be x shifted right by 4 bits
```

Here's another approach:

```
let val be 0
let hex_mask be 1
let bin_mask be 1
while hex_mask is not zero
  if (x and hex_mask) is non-zero, then update val to be val or bin_mask
  shift hex_mask left 4 bits
  shift bin_mask left 1 bit
```

**Addition**

Since you say it's not homework, let me show you that the second solution actually *is* a solution with only bitwise operators if you have a good compiler.

Here's code:

```
uint16_t hex_coded_binary_value(uint16_t x) {
  uint16_t val = 0;
  for (uint16_t h = 1, b = 1; h; h <<=4, b <<= 1)
    if (x & h) val |= b;
  return val;
}
```

If you compile this with a recent version of Apple `clang`, you'll get:

```
mov eax, edi
and eax, 1
mov ecx, edi
shr ecx, 3
and ecx, 2
or ecx, eax
mov eax, edi
shr eax, 6
and eax, 4
or eax, ecx
shr edi, 9
and edi, 8
lea eax, [rdi + rax]
ret
```

Note no loops! It's all shift, and, or, add, and move. `gcc` uses conditional move instructions, but also no loops.

What's the algorithm the compiler has discovered?  If you were coding in C, it would look something like:

```
val = (x & 1)
    | ((x >> (4 - 1)) & (1 << 1))
    | ((x >> (8 - 2)) & (1 << 2))
    | ((x >> (12 - 3)) & (1 << 3));
```

This folds to

```
val = (x & 1) | ((x >> 3) & 2) | ((x >> 6) & 4) | ((x >> 9) & 8);
```

Note that the result has fewer operations than @tom's solution.

This also compiles to essentially the same as the original, but the C is longer and more error prone.  The moral is to trust your compiler.

Comment: It is not for an homework but your algorithm works well. :) However I was more looking for a way to do this using only bitwise operators, the loop is pretty simple indeed. I clarified this in my OP.

Comment: @JeremyPare Please see the addition. Often, trying to beat the compiler is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

A one line fix for 16bit hex would be....

```
bin = ((hex%16)?1:0) + (((hex/16)%16)?2:0) + (((hex/256)%16)?4:0) + (((hex/4096)%16)?8:0);
```

though this is no the bitwise operations you want. Not sure if `>>` works on `int` or at least is specified to always work on `uint16_t` - You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213330/cast-from-int-to-unsigned-short-after-applying-bitwise-operator) to think about bitwise operators and `uint16_t` - if it is ok then

```
bin = (hex & 1) |
      (((hex >> 4) & 0x1) << 1) |
      (((hex >> 8) & 0x1) << 2) |
      (((hex >> 12) & 0x1) << 3);
```

would work given that your `hex` bytes are either `F` or `0`.

Old answer for arbitrary size hex is below

```
int hex;
int bin;

int n, m, k;

//assume hex has your hex value
n=0; bin=0;
while(pow(16.0,(double)n)<(double)hex+0.5) // test if we are done
 {
  m=1; for(k=0;k<n;k++) m*=16; 
  if ((hex/m)%16!=0) {
     m=1;for(k=0;k<n;k++) m*=2;
     bin += m;
  }
  n++;
 }
```

this should convert any 0x.... into 0b.... where you get a 1 for each digit if the hex digit is not equal to zero. The key part is `(hex/m)%16!=0` which tests the nth digit of the `hex` number to see if it is zero or non zero.

Comment: @JeremyPare - NB just edited with bitwise solution, but I would proceed with care for that..... glad it was helpful