# Why do C datatypes have these specific sizes on this machine?

Tags: c, types

I notice that C datatypes' sizes [may vary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types). I wonder **what causes the specific sizes that this machine produces**:

```
$ cat sizes.c
int main()
{
    printf("void *:%ld\n", sizeof(void *));
    printf("char:%ld\n", sizeof(char));
    printf("short:%ld\n", sizeof(short));
    printf("int:%ld\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("long:%ld\n", sizeof(long));
    printf("long long:%ld\n", sizeof(long long));
    printf("float:%ld\n", sizeof(float));
    printf("double:%ld\n", sizeof(double));
    printf("long double:%ld\n", sizeof(long double));

    return 0;
}

$ ./sizes
void *:8
char:1
short:2
int:4
long:8
long long:8
float:4
double:8
long double:16
```

Is this because my machine is:

- Linux?
- 64 Bit?
- Ubuntu?
- Old?
- A desktop distro? (as opposed to mobile, i.e. Android)
- Full of eels?
- Using an Intel processor?
- Using GCC to compile?
- Something else?

Here are the system details:

```
$ uname -a
Linux melancholy 3.13.0-46-generic #77-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 2 18:23:39 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS \n \l

$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.13.0-46-generic (buildd@tipua) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #77-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 2 18:23:39 UTC 2015

$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 60
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4460  CPU @ 3.20GHz
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x12
cpu MHz         : 3201.000
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips        : 6400.67
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

... Another three identical processors ...
```

To clarify, I'm not implying that there is anything wrong with the system. Rather, I would like to know why the values are what they are so that I could anticipate on what systems they will be different so that I could write portable code.

Comment: add in `sizeof(void *)` for good measure

Comment: [This document](http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html) might answer your questions. That model is called **LP64** .

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Added as per your request.

Comment: Here is another post with I think the same goal:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331751/does-the-size-of-an-int-depend-on-the-compiler-and-or-processor

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Thank you, that document is a good start. I guess I will have to try on other systems, such as on an Android phone.

Comment: @MatthewCarlson: Thank you, that link addresses the _theoretical_ aspect but not the practical. Also, as the OP there mentions, his question (a subset of the question, but does not encompass this entire question) remains unanswered for practical purposes. In any case, thank you for the link as it is definitely related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model there is **LP64**, meaning pointers and long are 64-bits; this is a standard for AMD64 on Linux and many more platforms; the other being the Windows **LLP64**, where only `long long` is 64 bits wide and `long` is 32 bits.

The usual choices are: `char` is the smallest addressable unit and preferably 8 bits. `sizeof(short)` is at least 2; if the processor supports this, then so be it. `int` is usually chosen to be the *fastest* integer type - on AMD64 architecture in 64-bit mode 32-bit registers are faster to use, or more supported than 16 or 64-bit registers (the 16 and 64 bit register modes require prefix bytes).

Now the reason why Windows uses `LLP64` is that of compatibility - lots of code has made the ill assumption that `long` is 32 bits; similarly in Unix world, it has been assumed that a pointer fits in `long` - now that the pointers are 64-bits, then the `long` must match that width.

---

To write portable programs, include the `<inttypes.h>` and use the constants there; otherwise assume that these types are of their minimum size (int 2 bytes, etc). Use `intptr_t`/`uintptr_t` for integer variables that should also be wide enough to hold a pointer - or use an union.

Comment: Agree that "int is usually chosen to be the fastest", yet going forward, even if `64-bit` is fastest, and the _usual_ need for a 1,2, and 4 byte type leaves C with as 32-bit `int`.

Answer (score 3):

I think its safe to say, from the practical point of view, the driving force would probably be the processor.

The associated architecture for the processor will undoubtedly make a difference on whether or not the size of int actually does change, but if you are targeting more than 1 specific processor( say, intel i3 530 ), then you will want to keep it in mind.

A 32 bit intel Pentium vs a 64 bit intel Pentium.

Arm 9 in a phone vs Arm 11 in a countertop POS machine.

etc.

One method of handling this issue, is to use int32_t, uint64_t and friends.  Where available, these would be guaranteed to be the same size: 32 bits for uint32_t etc..