# Cython: Buffer type mismatch, expected 'int' but got 'long'

Tags: python, numpy, cython, memoryview

I'm having trouble passing in this memoryview of integers into this (rather trivial) function. Python is giving me this error:

```
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int' but got 'long'
```

Can someone help me understand what's going on? Searching around stackoverflow, it seems that it has to do with how python interprets types, and how C interprets types.

```
%%cython
def myfunction(int [:] y):
    pass

# Python code
import numpy as np
y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
myfunction(y)
```

This produces the `ValueError` from above.

**EDIT:** Here are some other things I've discovered.

To clarify, this error persists if I declare `y` the following ways:

```
y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype='int')
y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=np.int)
y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=np.int64)
```

However, it works if I declare `y` with

```
y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=np.int32)
```

Does anyone want to give a suggestion why this is the case? Would throwing in `np.int32` work on different computers? (I use a macbook pro retina, 2013.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are using Cython's `int` type, which is just `C` `int`. I think on Mac (or most architectures) it is int 32-bit. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29) or [intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/size-of-long-integer-type-on-different-architecture-and-os) or [Does the size of an int depend on the compiler and/or processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331751/does-the-size-of-an-int-depend-on-the-compiler-and-or-processor)

On the other hand, `long` means int64. `dtype='int'` or `dtype=np.int` are all equivalent to `np.int64`.

I think you might just explicitly define it as one of the `numpy` type:

```
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
cdef myfunction(np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1] y):
     #do something
     pass
```

That way it reads more clear and there will not be any confusion later.

*EDIT*

The newer [memoryviews](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) syntax would be like this:

```
cdef myfunction(double[:] y):
    #do something with y
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Would throwing in `np.int64_t` work on every computer? (I know that I asked whether throwing in `dtype=np.int32` would work on all computers, but this option was in the python code. I'm wondering whether the `np.int64_t` option you provided above works on all computers, given it's cython code.)

Comment: I think so. Because it is in the function declaration, as long as we pass a `np.int64` array to it, it will do fine.  How internally `np.int64_t` would be translated into `C` type it `numpy`'s problem, not our problem (and I would trust it has already been taken care of, :P).  Sorry this is not a definitive answer, but I have seen this usage in tutorials and other peoples' code quite often.

Comment: I believe the memoryview syntax is now preferred to declaring it as a numpy array (it works more generally, and at the basically same speed). The point about the `np.int64` is right though.

Answer (score 1):

I did what the error message told me: I changed the `memoryview` base type from `int` to `long` and it seemed to work.

```
%%cython
def fun(long[:] x):
    return x[0]

y=np.array([1,2,3],dtype=int)
fun(y)    # returns 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Motivated by Yibo's answer, I used .astype(int), which resolved the issue.