# Program that determines if a number is odd or even shows the wrong output if number is longer than 5 digits

Tags: c, turbo

If I enter a number that's more than 5 digits long, it shows the wrong number. For example:

```
Enter Integer: 123456
-7616 is EVEN.-7616 is ODD.
```

My teacher wants us to use Turbo C++ but it sometimes freezes for me after I run a program so I used OnlineGDB (https://www.onlinegdb.com) (language: C (TurboC)) instead. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int number;

int main()
{
    clrscr();
    
    printf("Enter Integer: ", number);
    scanf("%d", &number);
    
    if ((number%2)==0)
    {
        printf("%d is EVEN.", number);
    }
    
    printf("%d is ODD.", number);
    
    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Your code will always print that the number is odd, since that `printf` is being executed unconditionally

Comment: Wow, the implementation of C you are using has a 16-bit `int`. It cannot handle numbers larger than 32767 in an `int` type. Try using `long`. When you change `int` to `long`, change `%d` to `%ld` in `scanf` and `printf`.

Comment: Since it's Turbo **C++** - you could use a `std::string` and just check the last `char`.

Comment: You say you use OnlineGDB, but that program does not compile in OnlineGDB because `clrscr` is not defined. When `clrscr();` and `getch();` are removed, the program handles 123456 as expected; it does not show the output you report. Edit the question to contain a [mre], including the actual source code being executed and the specific compiler and version being used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the size of C "int" 2 bytes or 4 bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438794/is-the-size-of-c-int-2-bytes-or-4-bytes)

Comment: [Does the size of an int depend on the compiler and/or processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2331751/327083)

Comment: @TedLyngmo You're making the very bold assumption that [Turbo C++ supports the STL](https://discuss.codechef.com/t/c-stl-standard-template-library-in-turbo-c/696). :-)

Comment: [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589575/327083)

Comment: If your teacher wants you to use Turbo C, your teacher will not expect your program to work for `int` values larger than 32767, so you're fine.  (Does your teacher also want you to eat Wooly Mammoth for lunch?)

Comment: @UnholySheep What does "executed unconditionally" mean? edit: I think I got it. I added else to my code.

Comment: @Dana "Unconditionally" means that the last `printf` call is not controlled by `if` or `else`.  It executes no matter what.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If I removed clrscr(); and getch();, it still shows the wrong output. But changing int to long solved the problem even if I didn't remove clrscr(); and getch();.

Comment: @Dana Those comments of Eric's referred solely to your claim that you'd switched from Turbo C to OnlineGDB.  You couldn't have run a program containing `getch` and `clrscr` on OnlineGDB.  So Eric was wondering what you *did* run there.

Comment: @Dana Oh!  I would never have imagined that OnlineGDB had a "Turbo C"setting!  Thanks for that clarification.

Comment: @SteveSummit I run the exact code on my question.

Comment: You forgot “else “ , so all numbers will be written as ODD (for odd numbers) or EVEN+ODD (for even number)

Comment: If by any possibility, run away from teachers urging you to use Turbo C++. It's multiple decades old...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `int` is a 16-bit integer. 123456 is greater than the 16-bit signed integer limit (32767), so `scanf()` can’t put the whole number into `number`. Instead, it gets truncated. 123456 is represented in binary as `11110001001000000`. That’s 17 bits, but only the last 16 can fit in `number`. With the leftmost bit gone, we have `1110001001000000`, which is **-7616** in [two’s complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) form (which is what an integer uses).

Try using a larger integer type, like `long`.

As others suggested in the comments, you may want to put the `printf()` for odd numbers in an `else`.