# alias for int32,int64

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Int64 a = Int64.MaxValue;
       Int64 b= Int64.MinValue;

       try
       {
          checked
          {
             Int64 m = a * b;

          }
       }
       catch (OverflowException ex)
       {
          Console.WriteLine("over flow exception");
          Console.Read();
       }
   }
}
```

if the variables are declared as int, i am getting the compilation error, conversion is requreid from int to long.

1. why am I getting this error although i am using int.
2. What are the alias `Int32` and `Int64`
3. When to use `Int32` and `Int64`, does it depend on OS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Int32 vs. Int64 vs. Int in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680111/int32-vs-int64-vs-int-in-c)

Answer (score 6):

`Int32` corresponds to `int`, `Int64` corresponds to `long`. For most general uses you can use 32-bit integers; however if you need very large numbers use `long` integers (64-bit).

When you assign `Int64.MaxValue` to an `int`, you're implicitly converting a `long` (`Int64`) to an `int` (`Int32`), which doesn't work. Besides, that value is way too large to fit in a 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Int32 = int
Int64 = long
```

CTS implementation  guarantee the types to be portable on any CPU/OS.

Answer (score 1):

int is int32 and long is int64.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> What are the alias Int32 and Int64

Alias of `Int32` is `int`. Alias of `Int64` is `long`.

> When to use Int32 and Int64, does it depend on OS?

Whether to use Int32 or Int64 depends on the application (range, sign requirement). And No, it does **NOT** depend on the OS. `int` will always be 4 byte long Int32 as long as .NET framework is concerned. Please also note that alias is a feature of compiler. So `long` does make sense when you are programming in C# but consider VB.NET developers who don't necessary like the property names like [Array.LongLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.longlength.aspx) since `long` doesn't make sense to them.

Answer (score 0):

1) You shouldn't get this error if you use int everywhere.  The following works fine:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = int.MaxValue;
        int b = int.MinValue;

        try
        {
            checked
            {
                int m = a * b;

            }
        }
        catch (OverflowException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("over flow exception");
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

2) `Int32` is aliased using `int`, `Int64` is aliased using `long`

3) This is not platform specific, but rather defined by the C# specification.  It is the same on all platforms.  Use `Int32` (or `int`) when you need a 32 bit integer, and `Int64` (or `long`) when you need a 64 bit integer.  This is more of a logic/algorithmic decision, not a platform related one.

Comment: when program runs, i will get the run time error. If make a and b has constants i will get compilation error. why such a difference

Comment: @Raghav: The compiler can help with constants - without constants, you get a runtime error.  The compiler helps when it can, but can't always do everything.  Think of the compiler errors as "helpful additions"

Answer (score 0):

`System.Int32` and `System.Int64` are types defined by the CLI standard (ECMA-335). They're basically the CLR/framework versions of the types for a 32 and 64 bit integer, and are guaranteed to be portable.

Some languages, like C#, define aliases to those types -- C# defines `int` to be the same as `System.Int32` and `long` to be the same as `System.Int64` -- consequently those types are also portable.

As to which you use (CLR version versus language version, at least), it is by and large a matter of style, especially if you are using only one language. I personally prefer to use the language-specified aliases for CLR types when possible.